# .NET CD burning component

Tags: .net, components, cd-rom

We are looking for a reliable 3rd party .NET component that can burn files onto a CDROM.  Any recommendations?

Comment: Windows API -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366450(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one  [http://www.binarymagics.com](http://www.binarymagics.com/) or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336741.aspx or even this one http://www.primoburner.com/

Maybe this one http://www.bayden.com/delphi/cdburner.htm